# How to compile file that uses hidapi with g++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, include, hidapi

I have a single `main.cpp` file with this content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>
#define MAX_STR 255

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    int res;
    unsigned char buf[65];
    wchar_t wstr[MAX_STR];
    hid_device *handle;
    int i;
    
    cout << "Hello\n";
    
    res = hid_init();
    handle = hid_open(0xC251, 0x2201, NULL);
    
    return 0;
}
```

where [`hidapi`](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) was installed following the instructions for Ubuntu 20.04, i.e. `sudo apt install libhidapi-dev`. Now I want to compile this with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

but I get `` main.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `hid_init' ``. How am I supposed to make this work? (Note that I had to write `#include <hidapi/hidapi.h>` instead of `#include <hidapi.h>` because otherwise it would complain about this also, not sure if this is related with the current issue.)

Comment: You forgot to link with the library.

Comment: How is that done? I have tried with `g++ main.cpp -o main -lhidapi`, `g++ main.cpp -o main -lhidapi/hidapi`, `g++ main.cpp -o main -lhidapi -Lhidapi`, `g++ main.cpp -o main -lhidapi -Lhidapi/hidapi` but don't work.

Comment: Find the path, where `libhdiapi.lib` is located afterinstallation and build,  and configure that additionally with the `-L` option.

Comment: I am in Linux, not an expert but I think that `.lib` is for Windows. I have found some `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhidapi-hidraw.so` but when I add this path with `-L` it still fails. For example `g++ main.cpp -o main -lhidapi-hidraw.so -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. I have tried several combinations of `-l` and `-L`. Is it correct having to hardcode the path for each library you include in a C++ program? Isn't there something like Python that you just `import bla` and it works out of the box?

Comment: `"...it still fails"` is not a very useful description of the problem.  Please edit your question to show both the compile/build command you invoke and the error messages verbatim.  Note that if the symbol you're looking for is in `libhidapi-hidraw.so` then the linker option should probably be `-lhidapi-hidraw` rather than `-lhidapi-hidraw.so` .

Comment: Then try finding `libhidapi.a`, which is the appropriate stubs, you shouldlink with. And no, there isn't something "simple" like `import` unless you use c++20 ready APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I replaced `-lhidapi-hidraw.so` by `-lhidapi-hidraw` and now it compiled.